# How to find the biggest number in a sentence from a file and then print it?

Tags: python

I just want to know how to find the biggest number in a sentence and then print it because i'm working on a project which involves putting the player's name and how many points they got. The format in the file look like this: player 1 (username) got 20 points. I don't know if this is right but it might have to do with this

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
print('The biggest number is: ' + str(max(s)))
```

but I want it so that it takes the biggest number from sentence from file and the file format looks like this 'john has 58 points'.

Comment: This is far too broad. What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: ok then how to print the sentence with biggest number that is in a sentence e.g john has 58 points    bob has 46 points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do this:

```
f = open("file.txt","r")
lines = list(f) #create a list of strings
f.close() #don't forget to close our files when we're done. It's good practice.
modified_lines = [] #empty list to put our modified lines in (extracted number, original line)
for line in lines: #iterate over each line
    if line.strip(): #if there's anything there after we strip away whitespace
        score = line.split(' ')[2] #split our text on every space and take the third item
        score = int(score) #convert the string of our score into a number
        modified_lines.append([score, line]) #add our modified line to modified_lines

#sort our list that now has the thing we want to sort based on is first
sorted_modified_lines = sorted(modified_lines, reverse = True )

#take only the string (not the number we added before) and print it without the trailing newline.
for line in sorted_modified_lines:
    print(line[1].strip()+"\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

This code will read your data from file 'data' and convert its content to python dict using format you supplied: (player) has (points) points, and then find player with maximum amount of points and print that player name and his points.

```
import operator

file = open('data', 'r')
file_content = file.read().splitlines()
file.close()

users_points = {i.split()[0]: int(i.split()[2]) for i in file_content}
best_player = max(users_points.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]

print('player with maximum points is {}, this player has {} points'.format(best_player, users_points[best_player]))
print(sorted(users_points.values())) # This will print points of all players
```

---

proof of function:

```
s = '''john has 58 points
bob has 46 points
fred has 0 points
leo has 27 points
max has 34 points'''

import operator

file_content = s.splitlines() # no file available here, but result is the same

users_points = {i.split()[0]: int(i.split()[2]) for i in file_content}
best_player = max(users_points.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]

print('player with maximum points is {}, this player has {} points'.format(best_player, users_points[best_player]))
print(sorted(users_points.values())) # This will print points of all players

best_players = sorted(users_points, key=users_points.get, reverse=True)
for bp in best_players:
    print('{} has {} points'.format(bp, users_points[bp]))
```

leads to output:

```
player with maximum points is john, this player has 58 points

[0, 27, 34, 46, 58]

john has 58 points
bob has 46 points
max has 34 points
leo has 27 points
fred has 0 points
```

Comment: thanks for this also i have another question how would you make it so that it takes all of the scores and print them in order. highest score to the lowest score

Comment: print(sorted(users_points.values())) add this line to end of script to print all values in ascending order.

Comment: how would you make it so that it doesn't only print the values in order but it prints the scores with the sentences as well e.g (john has 58 points) then underneath it sayes the second highest score (bob has 46 points)

Comment: best_players = sorted(users_points, key=users_points.get, reverse=True) This way you can get all players names sorted by their score, just print them and their score that is in users_points

Comment: Nice solution, especially use of `operator`, which I never heard of before. I'll have to look at it. +1

Comment: im getting this error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\YT\Desktop\test score.py", line 10, in <module>
    print('player with maximum points is {}, this player has {} points'.format(best_players, users_points[best_players]))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: It's two times `best_player`, not `best_players`. Probably you have a list called `best_players`, but a list is not possible there.

Comment: However, this is the difference I saw in what you posted claiming an error and the original code by Filip. The code works, see my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

Solution with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Suppose the file looks like

```
john has 58 points
bob has 46 points
fred has 0 points
leo has 27 points
max has 34 points
```

The import is simple and handles basic type casts automatically

```
df = pd.read_table(filename, sep=' ',  usecols=[0,2], names=['name', 'points'])
```

and once sorted

```
srtd_data = df.sort_values('points', ascending=False)
```

all your requests are quite simple to realize:
list of winner and his points:

```
srtd_data.loc[0].values

['john' 58]
```

list of all points sorted:

```
srtd_data.points.values

[58 46 34 27  0]
```

sorted sentences:

```
srtd_data.apply(lambda x: '{} has {} points'.format(x[0], x[1]), axis=1))

0    john has 58 points
1     bob has 46 points
4     max has 34 points
3     leo has 27 points
2     fred has 0 points
dtype: object
```

Comment: is this possible to do without pandas cause my school don't have that

Comment: also could u check the code cause im getting an error also could you write all the code together at the end please

Comment: Of course it's possible without pandas. Just look e.g. at the solution of Filip Młynarski.

Comment: I tested the code before I posted it, it works. The results below every command are actually the real results of each command. If you get an error and do not know how to debug a program, nobody can help you if you not at least share the (complete) error message.

Comment: No, sorry, why should I copy and paste all the code to the end again?

Comment: Filip Młynarski code does  work but it doesn't display the scores like you have done

Comment: Yes, but only because Filips code isn't about formatting, it's about giving you the information you wanted to have. Formatting it the way however you like is up to you.

Comment: also above you told me that it is 'best_player' but that sill doesn't work